# What exactly is "next()" in middleware and how does it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, middleware

I'm following Net ninjas tutorial on node.js and I'm trying to make my own examples so I can get the concepts down in my head. When I do this I follow along with the GitHub source code on his profile. I got stuck on this part:

```
// middleware & static files

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.locals.path = req.path;
next();
});
```

When I learn code, I make it my goal to know not only ***what*** works, but ***why*** it works. That being said, I have two questions:

1. Why can I get away with not using "next()" on the lines 1-3, but not 4?
2. Why is line 4 even necessary to begin with? Net ninja never explains it in his video where he talks about middleware.

Comment: I think you can find all the information for your questions about Express middleware from [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) :). The document is very clear in my opinion. If you have any question, feel free to add a comment :)

Comment: `next` lets the internals know to call the next callback (if any) in the queue, eg if you added yet another callback in your own code your first callback would be called then `next` would tell the internals to call the next one in line(your second callback). The first ones just call `next` internally

Answer (score 2):

The structure of an ExpressJS server looks like an onion, where each layer is a different Middleware. [As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK0HK.jpg)

A request to the server will go through every middleware in order. The `next()` function tells Express that the current middleware finished it's businness with the request and that the execution should continue.

All middlewares call the `next()` function, you don't see it on lines 1-3 because they are inside the corresponding middleware's code.

---

If you just do

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

It means your "execution path" will be `Request -> Morgan -> App -> Morgan -> Response`.

Similarly, if you do

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(debug);
```

Your "execution path" will be `Request -> Morgan -> Debug -> App -> Debug -> Morgan -> Response`.

---

You may have noticed that the middlewares are shown twice on the path. That's due to EspressJS structure and it means that a middleware can have more than one `next()`. The first `next()` is called after processing the Request and the second one is called after processing the Response.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // Start some work
    next(); // Stop work and continue to the next middleware
    // Resume work
    next(); // Finishes execution and continue to the next middleware
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Each request will go through all the middlewares that you have specified and in the exact order in which they are specified.

When you are creating your own middleware, you can use the `req`, `res` and `next` inside it. Sometimes one middleware will not do whole logic, but only the part of it, so that middleware can modify the `req` and `res` and then it can call `next()`. `next()` means that modified `req` and `res` objects will be passed to the next middleware.

Also, when you want to handle an `error`, you can just pass the `error` with `next(error)` and then the `Error Handler` will be triggered.